# Console behavior in synchronous thread firefox

Tags: javascript, execution, synchronous, console.log

My question is about the code I show below (I know it's a bad code, because I use a while that way).

I expected this output order as the script is executed:
1. The **Hello** message is displayed.
2. Javascript processes for 3000 ms.
3. The message **approx. elapsed time 3000** is displayed.

But what happens is that:
1. The browser blocks for 3000 ms.
2. The **Hello** message is displayed.
3. The message **approx. elapsed time 3000** is displayed.

I've been reading something and they indicate that the Developers Tools extension runs in another thread, but that still doesn't explain why it doesn't behave like in other languages like C# for example.
Thank you for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Hello");
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var diff_time = now-start;
    while (diff_time<3000){
        now = new Date().getTime();
        diff_time = now-start;
    }
    console.log("aprox. elapsed time 3000");
</script>
```

Comment: I know that it is not your question, but if it is bad code, why do you want to keep it? you should be using setTimeOut...That way you will ensure that whatever logic needs to be executed after the 3000 ms would happen accordingly

Comment: DavidEspino , I'm not going to use that code, I just want to know what part of the browser or Javascript is what makes the result in that way.

Comment: It's the whole of the browser that makes the log not appear on the screen until the JS execution has finished. Does it matter? It should not be a problem.